# Android Asynctask run twice in Fragment Tabs

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments

My Asynctask run twice when my fragments were reattached. How can I make it attach only once. This causes Content View Not Yet Created when I quickly switch between tabs when it is running my asynctask. Anyone got any solution to this problem?

```
  public class AndroidFragment extends SherlockListFragment  implements ActionBar.TabListener{

static final String URL = "https://xml.xml";
static final String KEY_SONG = "song";
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_CAT_ARTIST = "artistcat";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
static final String KEY_BIG_URL = "big_url";
static final String KEY_CAT_URL = "cat_url";
static final String KEY_DESC = "cat_desc";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
ListAdapter adapter;
Context appContext;
private Fragment mFragment;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        new loadListView().execute();

        if (getActivity() != null) {
            adapter=new MainPageLazyAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems);
            setListAdapter(adapter);}

     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }

public class loadListView extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... args) {
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_CAT_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_CAT_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
            map.put(KEY_BIG_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_BIG_URL));
            map.put(KEY_CAT_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_CAT_URL));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
            return null;
        }   


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {

     }
}

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = new AndroidFragment();
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
            //ft.attach(mFragment);

        } else {

            if (mFragment.isDetached()){
                ft.attach(mFragment);
            }


        }
        }


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        ft.detach(mFragment);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }


}
```

LOGCAT :

```
  10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab/in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.MainPageLazyAdapter.getCount(MainPageLazyAdapter.java:34)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:460)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListAdapter(ListFragment.java:182)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:365)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtab.AndroidFragment.onViewCreated(AndroidFragment.java:52)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:505)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1136)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1943)
10-09 15:21:47.141: E/AndroidRuntime(7582):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post complete code of your class. Otherwise, we cant help you out.

Comment: I just edited. Please check Trickster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that AsyncTask is running twice? Because what I am getting from your code and logcat is when AsyncTask is completed and onPostExecute is called (considering your fragment is currently detached) if you call setListAdapter at that time when list is not created, you get this exception. So instead of calling setListAdapter in onPostExecute, save the downloaded items in fragment and set it as adapter in onViewCreated(). Give it a try and tell me is this solve your problem.

Use this code.

```
public class AndroidFragment extends SherlockListFragment  implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    static final String URL            = "https://xml.xml";
    static final String KEY_SONG       = "song";
    static final String KEY_ID         = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE      = "title";
    static final String KEY_CAT_ARTIST = "artistcat";
    static final String KEY_DURATION   = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL  = "thumb_url";
    static final String KEY_BIG_URL    = "big_url";
    static final String KEY_CAT_URL    = "cat_url";
    static final String KEY_DESC       = "cat_desc";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    Context     appContext;
    private Fragment mFragment;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        new loadListView().execute();

        if (getActivity() != null) {
            adapter = new MainPageLazyAdapter( getActivity(), menuItems );
            setListAdapter( adapter );
        }

        super.onViewCreated( view, savedInstanceState );
    }

    public class loadListView extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground (Integer... args) {
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl( URL ); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement( xml ); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName( KEY_SONG );
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item( i );
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put( KEY_ID, parser.getValue( e, KEY_ID ) );
                map.put( KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue( e, KEY_TITLE ) );
                map.put( KEY_CAT_ARTIST, parser.getValue( e, KEY_CAT_ARTIST ) );
                map.put( KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue( e, KEY_DURATION ) );
                map.put( KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue( e, KEY_THUMB_URL ) );
                map.put( KEY_BIG_URL, parser.getValue( e, KEY_BIG_URL ) );
                map.put( KEY_CAT_URL, parser.getValue( e, KEY_CAT_URL ) );
                map.put( KEY_DESC, parser.getValue( e, KEY_DESC ) );
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add( map );
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (String args) {
            if (adapter != null) adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected (Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = new AndroidFragment();
            ft.add( android.R.id.content, mFragment );
            //ft.attach(mFragment);

        } else {

            if (mFragment.isDetached()) {
                ft.attach( mFragment );
            }


        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected (Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        ft.detach( mFragment );

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected (Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry Trickster, I'm not sure if i'm doing this correctly or not. I caught an error. Please check my codes and my logcat.

Comment: I never use notifyDataSetChanged before. Somehow i got this error when i try your codes. The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter

Comment: Whats the parent class of your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this hasn't to be there, try to delete it:

```
else {

        if (mFragment.isDetached()){
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide a more thorough explanation to help the OP?